# Find the digit of the units for the number $(5)(7^{29})+(8)(9^{72})$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was checking the following number theory exercise:

> Find the digit of the units for the number
>
> $(5)(7^{29})+(8)(9^{72})$

Here goes what I have:

$5 \equiv -5$ $(mod$ $10)$

$7^{29}\equiv $ $7(mod$ $10)$

$8 \equiv -2$ $(mod$ $10)$

$9^{72}\equiv $ $1(mod$ $10)$

Then $-5+7-2+1 = 1$. So $1$ should be the digit of the units, but the answer is three.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be $(-5)\cdot 7 + (-2)\cdot 1$?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing $(-5)7+(-2)1$?

Answer (score 2):

$9^n$ has a units digit of $9$ if $n$ is odd, and a units digit of $1$ if $n$ is even. This is pretty easy to prove/test. So, $8\cdot 9^{72}$ has a units digit of $8$.

We do a similar thing for $7$

$7^1$ = 7

$7^2$ = 49, so units digit is $9$

$7^3$ has units digit of $3$, since $7^2$ had a units digit of $9$ and $7*9 = 63$.

$7^4$ has a units digit of $1$, since $7*3 = 21$.

So, there is a pattern in the units digits of exponents of $7$. The pattern seems to be $1,7,9,3,1,7,...$. Then, since $29 \ \text{mod} 4 = 1$, we can say that $7^{29}$ has the same units digit as $7^1$, so it ends in $7$. Multiplied by $5$ gives us a units digit of $5$. We add the two units digits together to get $13$, so the number has a units digit of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

HInt:

$7\equiv1\pmod2,7^n\equiv1^n\equiv1$

$\implies5\cdot7^n\equiv1\cdot5\pmod{2\cdot5}$

$9\equiv-1\pmod5\implies9^{2m}\equiv(-1)^{2m}$

$\implies8\cdot9^{2m}\equiv8\cdot1\pmod{8\cdot5}\equiv8\pmod{2\cdot5}$

Answer (score -2):

All of the answers so far are correct, but they needlessly look at the value of the factor $7^{29}$. Any odd multiple of $5$ has a $5$ in the units place, and $7^{29}$ is plainly odd. No need to analyze any further. Add that $5$ to the $8$ found by the others, and the answer is $3$ a little more directly.

Comment: One other answer is based on exactly this remark.

Comment: My intent was to offer an insight which traverses any explicit consideration or manipulation of either $7$ or $7^n$ or $7^{29}$, such as are present in all other answers. No surprise that some explicit analyses and the insight may touch the same logical bases, since they all arrive at the same answer.

Comment: No, one of the other answers "manipulates" $7^{29}$ exactly as you do, to say that it is congruent to $1$ mod $2$.

Comment: $7^{29}$ is a red herring; it can be replaced by any $x^y$ where $x>0$ is odd and $y\ge 1$ and the answer to the question would be the same. I did not rely on a specific step that identifies and uses $1$ as the factor to multiply $5$ by; rather that $5$ times any odd number (any number ending in $1,3,5,7,9$, not just $1$) has a $5$ in the units place. True, that can be established from the definition that $x\equiv 1\mod{2}$ for any odd $x$ (or in the alternative by simple demonstration). My answer traverses the need for that explicit argument.

Comment: "rather that 5 times any odd number" Sure you did. Exactly as another, earlier, answer.